# MSBuild : how to suppress the warning summary at the end of the build

Tags: .net, msbuild, build-automation

On a MSBuild Script, all errors and warnings are written twice :
- once they occured
- at the end of the build as a summary

I've heard it was possible to avoid the summary at the end of the build however I didn't find the option in the documentation.

Does everybody know this option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary` or `/fileloggerparameters:NoSummary` options.

See `msbuild /?` for more information / detail.